# Image recolour in Excel

Tags: vba, image, excel

I have a greyscale image with some transparent sections too. I would like to recolour this within excel (based on the value that a user types in a cell or something)

Manually, all I need to do is select the picture then in the ribbon  `format`  `colour`  `more variations`  `more colours` and select appropriately. I've tried the macro recorder on these steps but get nothing useful.

Searching the web has led me to believe that the `Shape.PictureFormat.Recolor` method, which I'm guessing is what I want, is [only availible in Publisher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff939364(v=office.15).aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-2nZrOjc2y5HMSV.Iu1U1zg&tduid=(0b457039b759bf6a123ada2a3e075770)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-2nZrOjc2y5HMSV.Iu1U1zg)()). I'd rather not interface with thatfor portability reasons (in case publisher isn't installed), and I'd also like this to run as speedily as possible.

I've even considered converting the image to an array of bytes, performing the required pixel manipulations then converting back to an image, but I think that'll be slow. I also don't have a clue how.

Is there a method in VBA to recolour an image in this way, leaving alpha as it is? Perhaps with the use of an ActiveX image control? Here's an example image in case it's not clear[image: recolour eg]
White  Green

Black  Black

Alpha  Alpha

Comment: No there is no inbuilt way to Recolor. You have only dew Object Members for  [PictureFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839432.aspx) The closest recoloring (sort of) that you can do is use [PictureFormat.ColorType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822545.aspx)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Any idea what msoPictureMixed does for the `ColorType`? I get an error when I try it

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a pure object model based solution, you can try to modify the document xml. It is not the easiest of solutions, but it is far easier than pixel manipulation.
Do like this:

1. Save your workbook without modification
2. Do the color change
3. Save the file again, with a different file name
4. Unzip the two *.xlsx files you created
5. Analyze the differences. You'll most likely find it in the *drawings* folder
6. Recreate the changes in the xml of the second file in the first one and zip it back together. If that works, you now have a theoretical way to the solution.

If you get this to work, you can automate these steps.